# how to reduce a constraint with integer variable to binary variable in an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear

I have an optimization problem with some constraints and binary and integer variable:
[image]

In which [image] is an integer variable and y is a binary variable. Now I want to reduce constraint (12) to the constraint without [image] (integer variable) and just include binary variable y. I rewrite the reduced constraints as follows:

[image]

But I am not sure that this conversion is correct or not, Could you please help me?

Comment: define M, D and why do you need to convert integers into binaries ?

Comment: Does not make sense to me. Assuming `z≥0`, the constraint `0≤y(i,j)+Mz` is nonsensical. You cannot use < or > in optimization, only ≤ and ≥.